# CiviCRM + Gmail not working anymore after updating to 5.40.2

Tags: email, smtp

After updating to **5.40.2** (running with Wordpress 5.8 on CentOS with CPanel), I cannot send anymore e-mails with SMTP and Gmail.

Using smtp.gmail.com and port 587 as I have always done returns: `STARTTLS failed`.

Using smtp.gmail.com and port 465 returns, when sending a test email:

```
Failed to connect to smtp.gmail.com:465 [SMTP: Invalid response code received from SMTP server while sending email. This is often caused by a misconfiguration in Outbound Email settings. Please verify the settings at Administer CiviCRM >> Global Settings >> Outbound Email (SMTP). (code: -1, response: )]
```

Using ssl:// has never worked for me and isn't working now (it returns `fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Unknown error)` or `fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:587 (Unknown error)`).

`openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465` and `openssl s_client -starttls smtp -crlf -connect smtp.gmail.com:587` seem to work, so I don't think that's a firewall problem.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

What version did you upgrade from? You may have to set up CRED_KEYS in civicrm.settings.php. See https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/version-specific/#civicrm-534